# lync + Exchange on Same Server?

Tags: exchange-server, lync-2010, lync

I'm attempting to build a test infrastructure Active Directory + Lync + Exchange.  After installing Lync on my Exchange Server, I was unable to connect to Exchange.  I don't know for sure that I was able to connect to Exchange before I installed Lync though.  Rather than go through the installation process again, I'm hoping if someone can tell me for sure if Lync 2010 and Exchange 2010 can exist on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure from previous discussions with our infrastructure guys that this is a big no-no (I thought about doing the same), although can't find any evidence to back up this assertion!

[This ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/128560/office-communcations-server-and-exchange-on-the-same-machine) might help you with a possible workaround - its for OCS 2007 R2, but may apply to Lync too

You might get a better response asking this specific question on serverfault, given that it's more infrastrucure than dev related